# Easy pattern detection for 3D reconstruction

Tags: matlab, vision

Im currently working on a 3d reconstruction/pose estimation project. To be more specific i have implemented a method which is able to estimate the pose, given horizontal and vertical  line correspondences.

In order to have this method work, i need to create an easily detected pattern (the reference view) in which every single line detected (in others shots-view) can be distinguished from the others in such way i can tell which line is detected with respect to the reference view.

The problem is that i have hard time thinking of a pattern both good looking and functional. What i have come up so far is the pattern above in which given the color of the region, the line is detected, i can tell whether the line is vertical or horizontal and given the color of the line i can discrete the line to tell its coordinates in the reference pattern. Unfortunatly i find myself lost in all these detection methods and i lack the experience of working in such tasks, are there any methods relative to my task ?

Any help or idea is greatly appreciated.

PS: it is worth mentioning that the camera is already calibrated and i need this method to work in case the patter is partially occluded.

[image: pattern]

Comment: Why not the classic and widely used checker-board? Why is a requirement for the pattern to be "good looking"? Is it for a fashion show?

Comment: Forgive me for this, I forgot to mention that the camera is arleady calibrated and i want this method to work in cases where occlusion takes place.

Comment: You say that "every single line is detected". You just contradicted that

Comment: i meant every single line which the edge detection algorithm managed to detected , Not every single must be detected thought. 
By saying good looking i meant a better looking pattern than that i came up with. You can obviously tell that my pattern is pretty ugly.

Comment: "ugly" is both unscientific and unimportant. You want the one that will give you best results, regarthless of visual appeal

Comment: I agree with you using the term unscientific , but in my case im free to select any pattern which is functional and a good looking pattern would be nice. Althought as you said functionality is my first priority.